# Python 2.7 appending column to 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 arrays, x and y:

```
x = [[ 1.  2.  3.  4.]
     [ 5.  6.  7.  8.]
     [ 9.  0.  3.  6.]]

y = [[ 1.  0.  0.]
     [ 0.  1.  0.]
     [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```

I want a z matrix, as: z = [y[0], x, y[1], y[2]]:

```
[[ 1.  1.  2.  3.  4.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  5.  6.  7.  8.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  9.  0.  3.  6.  0.  1.]]
```

So I made this code:

```
z = np.c_[y[0], x]
for j in range(n):
   z = np.c_[x, y[j]]
```

But it is not saving the matrix. My resulting z was just the last operation:

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.  4.  0.]
 [ 5.  6.  7.  8.  0.]
 [ 9.  0.  3.  6.  1.]]
```

How could I save the changes made on the matrix? I also tried to numpy.append() the same way, but it gives an error message:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Comment: What's your desired output?

Comment: @allen I edited the question with the output

Comment: Why is the first row '[ 1.  1.  2.  3.  0.  0.  0.]' instead of '[ 1.  1.  2.  3.  4.  0.  0.]'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using np.c to stack columns of y and x..

```
np.c_[np.array(y)[0],np.asanyarray(x),np.array(y)[1],np.array(y)[2]]
Out[536]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, ..., 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 6, ..., 8, 1, 0],
       [0, 9, 0, ..., 6, 0, 1]])
```

Or you can use np.roll to shift the columns before stacking them and shift again afterwards.

```
np.roll(np.c_[np.array(x),np.roll(np.array(y),-1,axis=1)],1,axis=1)
Out[549]: 
array([[1, 1, 2, ..., 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 5, 6, ..., 8, 1, 0],
       [0, 9, 0, ..., 6, 0, 1]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the command you are looking for is `numpy.insert(a, pos, col, axis = 1)`. If you make `z = insert(y, 1, x, axis = 1)` it will insert a new column on y with the values from x, and save the output in z.